# How to group by looking at previous and next value in each row

Tags: sql, sql-server

Suppose I have a table with the following records...

```
ResumeId    Action
39092       DEV   
39092       C     
39092       C     
39096       C     
39096       C     
39098       CONF      
39098       CONF
```

How can I group them so that the output would look like this? In the below case, since `ResumeId = 39092` has at least one `DEV` record then the grouping result should return `DEV`...

```
ResumeId    Action  
39092       DEV     
39096       C       
39098       CONF
```

Comment: what if there is no DEV but C and CONF for a resumeid?

Comment: Your logic isnt complete.

Comment: If all resumeids with the same id have the same value (all are C), then the result should be that value (C)...

Comment: So the options are 1) every action for resume_id is the same 2) every action is for resume_id the same but there is also one ore more `DEV`?

Comment: However if there's a resumeid with different action values (DEV,C), then I want to group on only one of the values (in this case DEV)... I don't want to group on both values...

Comment: The options are 1) a resumeid always has the same action and I pick that value 2) a resumid has a mix of values and I want pick only one of the values...

Comment: Pick which value? random?

Comment: No not random, in the above example its DEV...

Comment: wow bastos dont you get it? You need to provide the whole logic, so if there is a MIX of combination and each produce a different result you need to provide that info.  Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

Comment: Sorry, but like I tried to explain, I only had that one case to implement the logic. Regardless, the solution bellow helped me a lot, and I'm choosing it as an answer...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is one method:

```
select resumeid,
       (case when max(action) = min(action) then max(action)
             when sum(case when action = 'DEV' then 1 else 0 end) > 0 then 'DEV'
             else '??'
        end)
from t
group by resumeid;
```

Your rules don't specify what to do if there are multiple `actions`, but none are `DEV`.